# JavaScript Date.getDay()

Tags: javascript

Is Date.getDay() culture sensitive?

What I mean is if getDay() is called on a Monday date, will it return 1 in US culture browser and 0 in French culture browser?

Thanks

Comment: If it makes you feel better, the ISO rules for calculating the week of the year use Monday for the first day of the week, Sunday the last.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will always return `0` for Sunday, etc.

From the [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> A weekday value of 0 specifies Sunday; 1 specifies Monday; 2 specifies Tuesday; 3 specifies Wednesday; 4 specifies Thursday; 5 specifies Friday; and 6 specifies Saturday.

There is no mention anywhere of locale-specific behaviour, and it would be an awful idea. Can you imagine the chaos?!

Answer (score 1):

It will always return 1 for Monday.